# Having problems loading PHP Driver for SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, loadmodule

I am trying to make use of the PHP driver for MS SQL Server version 1.0.

I have everything setup but I think I am having trouble loading up the extension **php_sqlsrv_ts.dll**. I have gone to the command line and try this:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0>php.exe --re sqlsrv
Exception: Extension sqlsrv does not exist

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0>php.exe --re sqlsrv_ts
Exception: Extension sqlsrv_ts does not exist
```

In my PHP.ini - I have:

```
;extension=php_sqlsrv.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_ts.dll
```

Thread safe is enabled for me hence the usage of **php_sqlsrv_ts.dll**. My extension_dir is correct because I load other modules from there. I also have Microsoft Native CLient 2008 too. Everytime I try to run my PHP script I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()
```

It must have something to do with the module not being loadaed up. I can get all extension info for MySQL but not for sqlsrv extension.

How can I get PHP to load this extension?

Thanks all

### EDIT

Apache_Error_log:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sqlsrv: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20060613\nPHP    compiled with module API=20090626\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlrpc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Oct 13 14:51:16 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 13 14:51:16 2009] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Tue Oct 13 14:51:16 2009] [notice] Parent: Created child process 11916
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sqlsrv: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20060613\nPHP    compiled with module API=20090626\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: sqlsrv: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
 in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  Module 'xmlrpc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Module 'xmlrpc' already loaded in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
```

Comment: If you are running this inside of apache, are there any errors when mod_php is loaded? They will appear in the apache error log.

Comment: Trying to have a look at this, it is 2GB large file! Years of PHP noobing.

Comment: Ok, I am having trouble oppening this file with anything! Will keep trying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a version mismatch. The module was compiled for an earlier version of PHP than is used for mod_php. You will need to compile the module using the version on the server.

Comment: According to  this - http://bit.ly/rHxnU - this should work with PHP 5.X.X - and I have PHP 5.3.0??

Comment: Try the 1.1-version (October 2009): http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=ccdf728b-1ea0-48a8-a84a-5052214caad9

Comment: See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlphp/archive/2009/10/07/sql-server-driver-for-php-1-1-is-now-available.aspx They mention "...while also providing support for PHP ver 5.3"

Comment: Thank you both so much! Connected! Jeff helped and then Stefan took it the next level!